# How to change fileupload name in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there any way to change the file name dynamically in angular js

```
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().filename(this)">
```

and in filename method  i am changing the file name but value is not changing how i can i change the file name in file upload

```
$scope.filename= function(e)
{

 for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) {

 var x =  e.files[i].name + "test";
 e.files[i].name =  x;
 /// here i am changing the file name but it shows its 
  read only property how can i change the name
  }
}
```

I want to change the upload file name...I have to assign file name for every uploaded file how?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.filename = function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) {

      var x = e.files[i].name.split('.')[0] + "test." + e.files[i].name.split('.')[1];
      console.log(x);
      e.files[i].name = x;

    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().filename(this)">

</div>
```

Comment: while your are assigning this x variable to this e.files[i].name = x; value is not assigning for "e.files[i].name" not changing to new value

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the angularJS, You can use a directive to change the file name.

```
.directive('fileName', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fileName: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      el.bind('change', function(event) {
        var files = event.target.files;
        var file = files[0];
        scope.file = 'Newname';
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Call the directive from the element.

```
<input type="file" file-name="fileName">{{fileName}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its readonly value, So you can use directive change file name. Try this code

```js
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.directive('file', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      file: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, e, attrs) {
      e.bind('change', function(event) {
        var files = event.target.files;
        var file = files[0];
        scope.file = file.name.split('.')[0] + "_test." + file.name.split('.')[1];
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});

function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.file = {};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <input type="file" data-file="file.file" />
  <div>Update File Name: {{file.file}}</div>


</div>
```